# Linux - Repairing bad blocks on a RAID1 array with GPT

Tags: software-raid, smart, bad-sectors, bad-blocks

The tl;dr: how would I go about fixing a bad block on 1 disk in a RAID1 array?

But please read this whole thing for what I've tried already and possible errors in my methods. I've tried to be as detailed as possible, and I'm really hoping for some feedback

This is my situation: I have two 2TB disks (same model) set up in a RAID1 array managed by `mdadm`. About 6 months ago I noticed the first bad block when SMART reported it. Today I noticed more, and am now trying to fix it.

[This HOWTO page](http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/badblockhowto.html) seems to be the one article everyone links to to fix bad blocks that SMART is reporting. It's a great page, full of info, however it is fairly outdated and doesn't address my particular setup. Here is how my config is different:

- Instead of one disk, I'm using two disks in a RAID1 array. One disk is reporting errors while the other is fine. The HOWTO is written with only one disk in mind, which bring up various questions such as 'do I use this command on the disk device or the RAID device'?
- I'm using GPT, which fdisk does not support. I've been using gdisk instead, and I'm hoping that it is giving me the same info that I need

So, lets get down to it. This is what I have done, however it doesn't seem to be working. Please feel free to double check my calculations and method for errors. The disk reporting errors is /dev/sda:

```
# smartctl -l selftest /dev/sda
smartctl 5.42 2011-10-20 r3458 [x86_64-linux-3.4.4-2-ARCH] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     12169         3212761936
```

With this, we gather that the error resides on LBA 3212761936. Following the HOWTO, I use gdisk to find the start sector to be used later in determining the block number (as I cannot use fdisk since it does not support GPT):

```
# gdisk -l /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.5

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sda: 3907029168 sectors, 1.8 TiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): CFB87C67-1993-4517-8301-76E16BBEA901
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 3907029134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2014 sectors (1007.0 KiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048      3907029134   1.8 TiB     FD00  Linux RAID
```

Using `tunefs` I find the blocksize to be `4096`. Using this info and the calculuation from the HOWTO, I conclude that the block in question is `((3212761936 - 2048) * 512) / 4096 = 401594986`.

The HOWTO then directs me to `debugfs` to see if the block is in use (I use the RAID device as it needs an EXT filesystem, this was one of the commands that confused me as I did not, at first, know if I should use /dev/sda or /dev/md0):

```
# debugfs
debugfs 1.42.4 (12-June-2012)
debugfs:  open /dev/md0
debugfs:  testb 401594986
Block 401594986 not in use
```

So block 401594986 is empty space, I should be able to write over it without problems. Before writing to it, though, I try to make sure that it, indeed, cannot be read:

```
# dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/null bs=4096 count=1 seek=401594986
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
4096 bytes (4.1 kB) copied, 0.000198887 s, 20.6 MB/s
```

If the block could not be read, I wouldn't expect this to work. However, it does. I repeat using `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sdb`, `/dev/sdb1`, `/dev/md0`, and +-5 to the block number to search around the bad block. It all works. I shrug my shoulders and go ahead and commit the write and sync (I use /dev/md0 because I figured modifying one disk and not the other might cause issues, this way both disks overwrite the bad block):

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/md0 bs=4096 count=1 seek=401594986
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
4096 bytes (4.1 kB) copied, 0.000142366 s, 28.8 MB/s
# sync
```

I would expect that writing to the bad block would have the disks reassign the block to a good one, however running another SMART test shows differently:

```
# 1  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     12170         3212761936
```

Back to square 1. So basically, how would I fix a bad block on 1 disk in a RAID1 array? I'm sure I've not done something correctly...

Thanks for your time and patience.